# Issue using .net web service from ColdFusion

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, enumeration

I've been running into some challenges with a web service I'm trying to use of from ColdFusion. The service (AccountsService), has a method, GetAccountLinksByUser that returns accounts associated with a given user.  This method accepts two arguments:

- UPN, which is just a unique string to identify the user.  This is no problem, as far as I can tell.
- sourceType.  This is ultimately a string, but is defined in the WSDL as simple type with one of three possible values.  Here's a relevant sections of XML from the WSDL:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="SourceType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="All"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Manual"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="System"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The problem is that I can't seem to just pass the string "All", "Manual", or "System" into the web service. The stub that CF generates has the following signature for this method:

```
getAccountLinksByUser(java.lang.String, org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.tfonline_services_accounts_datacontracts.SourceType)
```

This appears to suggest that I need to pass in an instance of org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.tfonline_services_accounts_datacontracts.SourceType.  However, I can't create an instance of that type (easily) as it doesn't appear to be in a class path that CF searches.  I tried wrapping the classes that CF generates into the /stubs directory into a jar and putting them in a class path.  This did work, in that I could now create an instance of org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.tfonline_services_accounts_datacontracts.SourceType, but I was still unable to pass that into the getAccountLinksByUser method.

As requested, here is the code I'm using to call the web service:

```
<cfset accountsService = CreateObject("WebService", "http://local.hostname/libraries/com/foo/bar/staging/AccountsService.wsdl") />
<cfset SourceType = CreateObject("java", "org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.tfonline_services_accounts_datacontracts.SourceType") />
<cfset accounts = accountsService.getAccountLinksByUser("username@domain", SourceType.All) />
```

More information.  The publisher of the web service does not publish their WSDL publicly.  This was emailed to me and I'm loading the WSDL from my my local development site.

The specific error I'm getting is:

Cannot perform web service invocation getAccountLinksByUser.
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:

> Cannot perform web service invocation getAccountLinksByUser. The fault
>   returned when invoking the web service operation is: ''
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

I'm not really sure where to head at this point.  Any suggestions?

The service is written in .NET.

Comment: Can you share the ColdFusion code that you have tried using to call the service?

Comment: does the workaround halfway down this thread help: http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:30232

Comment: @Miguel-F I've updated the question with some sample code to use the web service, another detail, and the specific error that CF is throwing.

Comment: @barnyr - I assume you're talking about Tom Jordahl post about copying the stubs to the class path and using enum.fromString()?  Well, yes.  I've put the classes on the class path (so I can create SourceType), but there's no fromString() on it.  Also, that post was from 2004 and, I think, about CF 6.

Comment: What happens when you just pass in a string? `<cfset accounts = accountsService.getAccountLinksByUser("username@domain", "All") />`

Comment: Web service operation getAccountLinksByUser with parameters {username@domain,All} cannot be found. Please note that this is with and without javacast("string", "...")

Comment: Try these steps to narrow down your issue. [Debugging ColdFusion Webservices](http://blog.daksatech.com/2011/04/debugging-coldfusion-webservices.html)

Comment: Yes I was Doug, I realised afterwards that that's pretty much what you're doing. Unfortunately, a lot of the webservices client stuff hasn't changed since CF6, so some of the advice out there still applies. We've had to resort to manually calling .Net webservices using CFHTTP before now. Not very nice, but it'll ultimately work.

Comment: First, did you try refreshing the webservice ie `refreshWSDL=true`? Because there should be no problem passing in a [string for the enumeration ](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b4.html) ie "All". The signature you described works fine for me with an old version (CF8), so something must be different.. What is your version of CF and .NET?

Comment: @barnyr - I'm working on trying to call the web service via cfhttp right now, actually.

Comment: @Leigh - Yea, I am using refreshWSDL=true.  I've also read over that page and agree that this *should* work with a string.  However, looking at the generated Java classes for the service, the getAccountLinksByUser clearly shows that it's expecting a SourceType object and not a string.  All the errors also seem to suggest that the issues are on CF's side, not .net.  I'm using CF 10 fully patched.  I' not sure what version is being used for .NET as it's published by a 3rd party.

Comment: @Doug - Interesting, I just tried the same code under CF10 and got the "..cannot be found" error. Let me try a few more tests. (Edit) No luck so far..

Comment: @Leigh - thanks for your assistance. I'm continuing to work on this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a few tests and it seems related to the switch to Axis2 in CF10. I am honestly not sure exactly *what* about enumeration's changed between 1 and 2. However, setting the version level back to Axis1 should do the trick:

```
<cfscript>
     args = { refreshWSDL=true, wsversion=1 };
     ws = createObject("webservice", "http://mysite/test.asmx?wsdl", args);
     result = ws.getAccountLinksByUser("test@somewhere.com", "All");
     writeDump(result);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: This does appear to have resolved the issue!  I had tried exactly this a few days ago, but I didn't think to delete the stubs before testing and got a false negative.  Thanks for pointing this out and getting me to try it again.