# Changes made to a WSDL webservice .cfc is not showing up in a dump of the object created with CreateObject in cfscript

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, wsdl

I'm using CF9 and have an app (let's call it App A) that needs to call a method inside a .cfc file inside a webservice dir of a 2nd app (App B). I am trying to access this method using a WSDL webservice createObject call inside a large block of CFSCRIPT code.

The method in App B's webservice CFC called 'ws_webservice.cfc' looks like this (core content removed)

```
<cffunction name="getAllDepartmentChildrenCodesRecursive" access="remote" returntype="String" displayname="Get All Department Children Codes Recursively">
    <cfargument name="parentUnitId" type="numeric" required="true">
    <cfset var childList = "">
    ...

    <cfreturn childList>
</cffunction>
```

In side App A inside another CFC is this call inside cfscript tag block:

```
    ws = createObject("webservice", "https://...myserver.../wf/webservice/wf_webservice.cfc?wsdl");
    writeDump(ws);
    abort;
```

At this point the dump does NOT contain the method above. It has loads of other methods from that service but not this particular method that was recently added. It's like something needs reloading or refreshing.

I have gone into the CF Admin > Caching page and cleared the cache for Components and Templates but to no avail.
I have flushed the browser's cache and reloaded the app to pick up changes in application scoped CFCs including the CFC in App A that calls the createObject().

I'm at a loss why this is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what version of CF you are using. This post, [refreshing a webservice in the cache](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2005/7/13/webservice%20cache), is for CF 7 but it may still be relavent. The code for the "fix" is:

```
<cfscript>
// service wsdl file
sdl   =   'http:/' & '/mydomain.com/WS/myservice.cfc?wsdl';
// create object
factory = CreateObject('JAVA', "coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory");
// reference to the XmlRpcService
RpcService = factory.XmlRpcService;
// refresh the object in question
RpcService.refreshWebService(sdl);

//some edits to show reinstantiation.
// now reinstantiate your object.
myObj = createObject("webserivice",sdl);
//call your methods
myObj.myMethod(....);

</cfscript>
```

If it does *not* work it is likely due to your CF version. Let me know if it fails and I'll scare up a later version.

Comment: ... or you could use the `refreshWSDL` argument in your `createObject("webservice")` call. [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385642/issue-using-net-web-service-from-coldfusion/15392076#15392076) is for CF10, but I believe `refreshWSDL` is supported from CF8 onward.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, I'm using CF9 here.
I tried Leigh's suggestion but that didn't work for me. As for Mark's suggestion, I assume the last three command lines are verbatim (copy and paste vs plugging in my object names.) What is not clear is how to reference my webservice object. This appears to refresh it only. In other words, how would I call a method in my webservice?

Comment: I missed this - sorry.  You would follow up after the refresh with your `createobject()` call. Under the hood CF goes out and get's the latest WSDL and recompiles the stub. Remember that you don't want to do this all the time (at runtime). This is for dev and deployment. You really _do want to cache_ your web service stub. Recompiling that JNI stuff is expensive.

Comment: I have
`sdl = 'http://' & CGI.HTTP_HOST & '/wf/webservice/wf_webservice.cfc?wsdl';`
so dumping sdl produces that string.
If I dump
`sdl.getAllDepartmentChildrenCodesRecursive(primeCampusID)`
it throws an error as I have this all within a try catch. So I'm not sure what I'm missing here.
I do understand that I wouldn't want to run the refresh in production.

Comment: YEah - read my comment again (I edited it - I mispoke the first time).  you have to reinstantiated it using createobject().

Comment: I edited the answer to include reinstantiation. But note, as with all stack overflow answers you must grasp the gist of what is being said and move from there through trial and error to a solution. There's no way that anyone here can fully debug your code.

Comment: It turns out both approaches work! At first it wasn't until I discovered that I didn't have access=remote in the webservice method I had added. I had temporarily set it to public and forgot to change it back to remote. Once I discovered that error, both Leigh's approach and Mark's approach work fine for refreshing the WSDL webservice object in CF9 at least.  **Thanks to both of you for providing the answers!**